# Raspberry Pi GPIO keeps saying it's low when powering transistor

Tags: python, gpio, raspberry-pi2, led

I'm having a problem with reading the state of my gpios on the raspberry pi. I'm using 13 gpios to power and control a 3x3 led cube. 9 of them for the leds, 1 to ground, and 3 for the transistors for the layers. The problem is if I try to read their state with

```
gpio.input(pin)
```

I'm getting the correct value for the led pins, but if I try the exact same for the transistor ones, it keeps saying they are off / low even when they are clearly powering them. When I disconnect the transistor pins and read again the value is correct.
So I  want to know if there is a way to fix this or if I'll have to find another way.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the resistor between the IO pin and the transistor base is too low. Therefore the base current is too high in the range that makes the IO pin unable to reach the voltage level that would be detected "High" by the processor. I suggest you to increase the base resistor value. If this is a generic small signal NPN transistor then a base resistor value in the range of few kOhm may be a good start to experiment with.